# node.js html parse with javascript not jquery

Tags: javascript, node.js, html-parsing

I have an html file on my disk.  the link is "https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/7s6tzsy19d27gta/5.htm?dl=1&token_hash=AAE9-q-mLQbNcS7qo_Kmre2_8pkzTwKW6ZJRSXOVe0JJlQ"

I have the following javascript: which will remove certain nodes

```
     element = document.evaluate('html/body/table | //p[text()="SYNONYMS"] | //p[text()="SYNONYMS"]/following-sibling::p[following::p[text()="TRANSLATION"]] | //p[text()="PURPORT"] | //p[text()="PURPORT"]/following-sibling::p|//a[text()="Bhaktivedanta VedaBase"]|//a[text()="Śrīmad Bhāgavatam"]',
     document,
     null,
     XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE,
     null);
     for (var index = 0, len = element.length; index < len; index++) {
     element[index].parentNode.removeChild(element[index]);
     }
```

I am using linux and have nodejs installed. HOw to use nodejs to apply this javascript on the file.

Comment: In your node server file, find where it loads the file, give it a conditional to make sure you do it to the right file (`if filename = something`, etc) and then just put that code right after loading it.  You'll have to convert it `toString()` probably before running this code on it though.  Not positive though since I've never used this code.

Comment: create document via jsdom https://github.com/tmpvar/jsdom, if you can use jquery, there are 2 equipvalent on npm repository: `jquery` or `cheerio`, `cheerio` is simple and faster then `jquery`